# I want to change the discord bot status dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

This is the code im using

```
async def on_ready():
    print(f'bots up')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name='.help'))
```

like every minute the status changes ,
I tried but it doesnt allow me to use other commands , I put this code but it would give a error saying i cant put message argument in **on_ready()**

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: The code you posted does not interfere with your bot's ability to respond to commands. If anything, `await bot.process_commands(message)` belongs at the end of `on_message`. To periodically change your bot's presence, you should set up a `discord.ext.tasks.loop` and [`.start()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.start) that inside of `on_ready`

Comment: can u send the code for tht ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I change the bots presence

```
async def status_task():
while True:
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=f"listining status"))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)# 10 as in 10seconds
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="playing status"))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.competing, name=f"competing status"))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.streaming, name=f"streaming status"))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

and then on_ready

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"bots up")
    bot.loop.create_task(status_task())
```

hopefully this works for you,(for the status_task) change the 10 seconds in between each to lets say 60 , then every minute it will change

Comment: Wat should I add above async def status task().....nothing?

Comment: nothing no, its not a bot.event nor anything else

Answer (score 0):

To periodically change your bot's presence, you can use a [`discord.ext.tasks.Loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop). A basic blueprint could look something like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks

bot = commands.Bot('.')

@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def switch_presence():
    # list of all activities to switch between
    activities = [
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name='First activity'),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name='Another activity')
    ]
    curr_activity = bot.activity
    # default to the first activity if not set or invalid
    if curr_activity not in activities:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=activities[0])
        return
    # use modulo to start from the beginning once the list is exhausted
    next_activity_index = (activities.index(curr_activity) + 1) % len(activities)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=activities[next_activity_index])

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    switch_presence.start()
```

With some modifications, you can put this into a Cog as well. That would allow you to keep one static activity list instead of dynamically creating it (simply create it in the Cog's `__init__` and store it as a class variable) and also store the index of the next activity centrally, eliminating the need to compute it every single time the loop is called